# Comparar dos arrays y agregar valores no repetidos a un nuevo array en Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estoy tratando de comparar dos arrays con longitudes diferentes y que los valores que no se repiten sean agregados a un nuevo array.

Quisiera saber como lo hago, a continuacion comparto mi codigo:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope, $rootScope) { 
        $rootScope.res=[];
    $scope.Array1 = [
  {
    "responsable": "S/N",
    "tipo": "S/N",
    "guid": "a7c2dd58-eb27-004e-e043-ac10360d004e",
    "nivel": "PREGRADO",
    "fecha_clase": "05-04-2016"
  },
  {
    "responsable": "S/N",
    "tipo": "S/N",
    "guid": "a7c2dd58-eb27-004e-e043-ac10360d004e",
    "nivel": "PREGRADO",
    "fecha_clase": "12-04-2016"
  },
  {
    "responsable": "S/N",
    "tipo": "S/N",
    "guid": "a7c2dd58-eb27-004e-e043-ac10360d004e",
    "nivel": "PREGRADO",
    "fecha_clase": "19-04-2016"
  },
  {
    "responsable": "S/N",
    "tipo": "S/N",
    "guid": "a7c2dd58-eb27-004e-e043-ac10360d004e",
    "nivel": "PREGRADO",
    "fecha_clase": "26-04-2016"
  },
  {
    "responsable": "S/N",
    "tipo": "S/N",
    "guid": "a7c2dd58-eb27-004e-e043-ac10360d004e",
    "nivel": "PREGRADO",
    "fecha_clase": "03-05-2016"
  },
  {
    "responsable": "S/N",
    "tipo": "S/N",
    "guid": "a7c2dd58-eb27-004e-e043-ac10360d004e",
    "nivel": "PREGRADO",
    "fecha_clase": "10-05-2016"
  },
  {
    "responsable": "S/N",
    "tipo": "S/N",
    "guid": "a7c2dd58-eb27-004e-e043-ac10360d004e",
    "nivel": "PREGRADO",
    "fecha_clase": "17-05-2016"
  }
];
$scope.Array2=[{"fecha":"05-04-2016"},{"fecha":"12-04-2016"},{"fecha":"19-04-2016"},{"fecha":"26-04-2016"},{"fecha":"03-05-2016"},{"fecha":"10-05-2016"},{"fecha":"17-05-2016"},{"fecha":"24-05-2016"},{"fecha":"31-05-2016"},{"fecha":"07-06-2016"},{"fecha":"14-06-2016"},{"fecha":"21-06-2016"},{"fecha":"28-06-2016"},{"fecha":"05-07-2016"},{"fecha":"12-07-2016"},{"fecha":"19-07-2016"},{"fecha":"26-07-2016"},{"fecha":"02-08-2016"}];

for(var a=0;a<$scope.Array2.length;a++){
  for(var b=0;b<$scope.Array1.length;b++){
    var fechasLista=$scope.Array1[b].fecha_clase;
    var fechaConvertida =$scope.Array2[a].fecha;
    if(fechasLista != fechaConvertida){
    //aqui es donde deseo que los valores que no estan repetidos se agreguen en $rootScope.res
     $rootScope.res.push({r:'no repetidos '+fechaConvertida});
    }
  }
}
}
```

finalmente los presento de la siguiente manera:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="r in res">
    {{r.r}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Espero me puedan ayudar. De antemano les agradezco

Comment: con repetidos ¿a que te refieres? acaso buscas los elementos del primer array cuyas fechas no estén presentes el segundo array?..se mas explicito. Gracias.-

Comment: Yo pensaría al revés. Si encuentro un elemento que existe, lo elimino de una de las listas con splice. El array resultante será los elementos que no están.

Comment: El arreglo con los elementos no repetido lo necesitas solamente para mostrar algo en la vista o necesitas manipular el arreglo para otra cosa?

Comment: ya lo pude solucionar @devconcept

Answer (score 1):

Puedes conseguirlo sin utilizar ninguna librería con [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter):

```
const uniqueArray = array1.filter(value => array2.indexOf(value) == -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Este problema va más allá de angular, ya que es un problema de programación general solucionado mediante javascript.

Una solución es utilizar la librería [lodash](https://lodash.com/) y su método [uniqBy](https://lodash.com/docs#uniq), de forma tal que filtre los elementos indeseados en base a una función que le indiques, dejando solamente los únicos.

Personalmente, utilizo siempre la libreria lodash ya que agrega muchas funciones que no vienen por defecto en JS y ayuda a que el código sea mucho más legible para los siguientes devs.

Answer (score 0):

Tu pregunta básicamente es: *¿Cómo puedo generar un un nuevo Array de objetos, en base a 2 arrays de objetos?*

Definiste tu primer objeto, digamos *objetoCurso* con: responsable, tipo, guid, nivel y ***fecha_clase***.

Tu segundo objeto, digamos *objetoFecha* solamente con ***fecha***.

Y quieres un array de objetosFecha, donde **NO** existan *objetosFecha.fecha iguales a objetoCurso.fecha_clase*

Puedes filtrar el array que te importa; *array2.filter* (objetosFecha) con la condición buscada; que NO **!** debe estar en array1. Existen otras formas de hacerlo, yo creo que me gusta esta:

```
let arrayFiltrado = array2.filter(objetoFecha =>
  !array1.some(objetoCurso =>
    objetoCurso.fecha_clase == objetoFecha.fecha
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo basta aplicar [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Ffilter) para aplicar un filtrado de los objetos no repetidos. Adicionalmente puedes usar [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) para una verificación rápida si tiene o no un elemento con fecha repetida en el segundo array.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.array1 = [{
      "responsable": "S/N",
      "tipo": "S/N",
      "guid": "a7c2dd58-eb27-004e-e043-ac10360d004e",
      "nivel": "PREGRADO",
      "fecha_clase": "05-04-2016"
    },
    {
      "responsable": "S/N",
      "tipo": "S/N",
      "guid": "a7c2dd58-eb27-004e-e043-ac10360d004e",
      "nivel": "PREGRADO",
      "fecha_clase": "12-04-2016"
    },
    {
      "responsable": "S/N",
      "tipo": "S/N",
      "guid": "a7c2dd58-eb27-004e-e043-ac10360d004e",
      "nivel": "PREGRADO",
      "fecha_clase": "19-04-2016"
    },
    {
      "responsable": "S/N",
      "tipo": "S/N",
      "guid": "a7c2dd58-eb27-004e-e043-ac10360d004e",
      "nivel": "PREGRADO",
      "fecha_clase": "26-04-2016"
    },
    {
      "responsable": "S/N",
      "tipo": "S/N",
      "guid": "a7c2dd58-eb27-004e-e043-ac10360d004e",
      "nivel": "PREGRADO",
      "fecha_clase": "03-05-2016"
    },
    {
      "responsable": "S/N",
      "tipo": "S/N",
      "guid": "a7c2dd58-eb27-004e-e043-ac10360d004e",
      "nivel": "PREGRADO",
      "fecha_clase": "10-05-2016"
    },
    {
      "responsable": "S/N",
      "tipo": "S/N",
      "guid": "a7c2dd58-eb27-004e-e043-ac10360d004e",
      "nivel": "PREGRADO",
      "fecha_clase": "18-05-2016"
    }
  ];

  $scope.array2 = [{
    "fecha": "05-04-2016"
  }, {
    "fecha": "12-04-2016"
  }, {
    "fecha": "19-04-2016"
  }, {
    "fecha": "26-04-2016"
  }, {
    "fecha": "03-05-2016"
  }, {
    "fecha": "10-05-2016"
  }, {
    "fecha": "17-05-2016"
  }, {
    "fecha": "24-05-2016"
  }, {
    "fecha": "31-05-2016"
  }, {
    "fecha": "07-06-2016"
  }, {
    "fecha": "14-06-2016"
  }, {
    "fecha": "21-06-2016"
  }, {
    "fecha": "28-06-2016"
  }, {
    "fecha": "05-07-2016"
  }, {
    "fecha": "12-07-2016"
  }, {
    "fecha": "19-07-2016"
  }, {
    "fecha": "26-07-2016"
  }, {
    "fecha": "02-08-2016"
  }];

  $scope.res = $scope.array1.filter(obj => {
    const exists = $scope.array2.some(obj2 => (
      obj2.fecha === obj.fecha_clase
    ));
    
    if (!exists) {
      return obj;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl" style="padding: 25px">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Responsable</th>
          <th>Tipo</th>
          <th>GUID</th>
          <th>Nivel</th>
          <th>Fecha</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="r in res">
          <td>{{ r.responsable }}</td>
          <td>{{ r.tipo }}</td>
          <td>{{ r.guid }}</td>
          <td>{{ r.nivel }}</td>
          <td>{{ r.fecha_clase }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```